# Authenticate WebApi requests via owin (for example google) from external application

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

I'm working on a project where user has access to windows application (UWP). There, he can login/register via social networks using OWIN. Based on this he gets access to WebApi. I can't find any tutorials of any kind on how to secure WebApi from unauthorized access with login/registration form on external application.

Comment: http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/ try this. It might help

Comment: a step by step Example: http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/how-to-using-facebook-to-authenticate-with-web-api-2-in-a-native-mobile-application/